# Scroll Down when navigating from Particular Page using Angular5

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a page which contains two main Category.

For Example, My page looks like:

Numbers:

1

2

3

Letters:

a

b

c

I can navigate to this page from so many places.

In my dashboard, I have a tab called Letters. When I click on that it has to navigate to this page and it has to scroll down to show the letters. I have tried like this.

```
<div class="main-container" #scrollMe [scrollTop]="scrollMe.scrollHeight">
    <div>Numbers</div>
    <div>Letters</div>
    </div>
```

The problem is whenever I am navigating to this page it is scrolling down and showing the letter first. My requirement is it has to scroll down only when I navigate from the dashboard.

Can anyone help me in this

Comment: pass a route data (boolean type), while navigating from dashboard check for it, if it is true apply your down scrolling

Comment: @M Balajivaishnav Could you please explain based on the condition, how i will  do scroll down in HTML

Comment: is this possible you to create a plunkr or stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

You can use [(activate)](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet#how-to-use) attribute of router to control scrolling
**app.component.html**

```
<router-outlet (activate)="onActivate($event)" ></router-outlet>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
onActivate(event) {
  if(event)==="DashboardComponent"){ //exact name of dashboard component
    //scroll, something like window.scroll(....);

  }
    ....
}
```